# How to get space after table row (with tabularx loaded)?

Tags: tabularx, vertical-spacing

I'm trying to use `\\[\bigskipamount]` to create white space between table rows, but with the `tabularx` package loaded, the space doesn't appear.
Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % to get expected behavior, comment this out
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{\linewidth}}
The machine has just finished evaluating an expression to
produce value~$v$; it is about to plug~$v$ into the hole in the top
frame of stack~$S$.
The~machine's next transition is determined by the syntactic form
of~the stack~$S$---usually by the form of the
topmost~frame---and possibly also by a property of~$v$.
\\[\bigskipamount]
The machine has just finished evaluating an expression to
produce value~$v$; it is about to plug~$v$ into the hole in the top
frame of stack~$S$.
The~machine's next transition is determined by the syntactic form
of~the stack~$S$---usually by the form of the
topmost~frame---and possibly also by a property of~$v$.
\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here are the results:

[image: unexpected behavior---no vertical space]

And if I comment out `\usepackage{tabularx}`, I get the results I hoped for:

[image: expected behavior]

What do I need to do to get the space I want with `tabularx` loaded?

Comment: This is unrelated to tabularx, it is from array package. You get the expected behaviour with array or an old bug left for compatibility without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected behaviour is not to get any additional space in this case, as the `p` column depth is already greater than the extra depth you added with the optional argument.

The change is unrelated to `tabularx` other than that that loads the `array` package which fixes this bug.

This is clearer to see if you add an extra column (making the age overfull here but ignore that)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{array} % to get same behaviour with or without this 
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{\linewidth}c}
The machine has just finished evaluating an expression to
produce value~$v$; it is about to plug~$v$ into the hole in the top
frame of stack~$S$.
The~machine's next transition is determined by the syntactic form
of~the stack~$S$---usually by the form of the
topmost~frame---and possibly also by a property of~$v$.
&zzz\\[\bigskipamount]
The machine has just finished evaluating an expression to
produce value~$v$; it is about to plug~$v$ into the hole in the top
frame of stack~$S$.
The~machine's next transition is determined by the syntactic form
of~the stack~$S$---usually by the form of the
topmost~frame---and possibly also by a property of~$v$.
&zzz\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here you see the same behaviour with or without `array` as the deep strut generated by `\\[\bigskipamount]` is attached to the baseline of the c column and so has no effect as the `p` column has more depth.

The behaviour of the optional argument `\\[..]` really should depend on thewhole row and not be affected just by the last column. The `array` package implementation ensures that is the case.

To add more space add a bigger length  to the optional argument or add a `\bigskip` at the end of the `p` entry or use `\\\noalign{\bigskip}`  (The booktabs package has some spacing commands to hide the `\noalign` primitive, but are equivalent to this)